# Find all $(x,y)$ pairs that solve a given diophantine equation and modular equation.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, diophantine-equations

Find all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}×\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$690x+1230y=210$$
$$23|(x+y)^{7777} $$

I solved the diophantine equation and got $$x=-112+41n ~\text{ and }~   y=63-23n$$
I simplified the congruence, and ended up with
$$(-49+18n)^{11}\equiv 0 \ (\text{mod }23)$$

And I'm stuck. I have no clue how to follow, any ideas?

Comment: $a^{11}\equiv0\bmod23\iff a\equiv0\bmod23$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite as $(23n-46-5n-3)^{11}\equiv -(5n+3)^{11} \pmod{23}$. Now it's equivalent to $(5n+3)^{11}=0\pmod {23}$. Now if $gcd(5n+3,23)=1$ then this contradicts Fermat's theorem since $11=\frac{23-1}{2}$. Thus $gcd(5n+3,23)$ is not $1$ and thus $23|5n+3$, this is necessary.

Comment: The last argument follows since $23$ is prime

Comment: Sorry, I lost myself there. Why does it contradict fermat's theorem if the gcd = 1?

Comment: Nvm I got it, thanks for the help

Comment: You are welcome